# Youtube API v3 on iOS app. My API key does not work, but somebody else's key does work on same application. Error 403

Tags: ios, api, youtube, youtube-api

This might be a direct question for the Youtube team at Google, but I thought of asking here first in case it also helps somebody else in the future.

I am using the simple API key (without OAuth 2.0) on an iOS application. This application is simply returning the list of video ids from a specific playlist id. I am supplying the playlist id as well.

When I use my API key that I received from the youtube/google console, I get an error 403 when making the playlistItems request call.
When using somebody else's key (I actually found it online on an example) the application works.
All I'm really changing is the API key. I am not changing the part or playlist id, and in both cases I am using the same iOS application.

My key has both YouTube Data API v3, and the YouTube Analytics API enabled in the google cloud console, along with other default elements that came enabled with this application in google cloud console.

While this approach works, I don't want to bill somebody else's API key for the requests made from my application, and I would also like to have stats of the API request from my iOS app.

Any suggestions?
Has anyone run into this before?

Thank you.

Comment: Try 1. toggling the API on and off 2. creating a new project. I'm not sure what's going on here, but I want to eliminate the possibility that the project is in some wedged state.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help. I tried option 1 for a few days without success.
My iOS bundle had a dash in it, so I remade the app with another bundle ID just in case, and remade the project in the google console (so recreated the project in the console) and now it works fine.

I don't think I mark this question as closed since your answer seems to be listed as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Actually, my API key decided to not work today again.
Oddly enough it was working yesterday and this morning it decided to not authorize me.
Back to square one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a known problem with bundle ids on console. For now, please don't use bundle id, your app should work fine.

You can track the issue in public issue tracker and put bundleid back, once it's fixed. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5770

Comment: Alright cool. I just tested it today without bundle id and it seems to be working fine.
Any downsides of releasing an app this way?

Comment: not at all. Since you can just add bundle id later from google console.

Comment: dumb but obvious question. what if I never include the bundle id later?