# Youtube Live Streaming API - create live stream is failed with "The request did not specify any iOS bundle ID"

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I try to send request:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams

Response failed with message:

"The request did not specify any iOS bundle ID. Please ensure that the client is sending it or use the API Console to update your key restrictions."

My OAuth 2.0 client ID (iOS) and API Key on the Google API Manager have right bundle iD. I send key=API_KEY.

How can I send my bundle id with the request? Or I have to do something else?

Comment: Can you explain me with more detail.? Means anywhere live streaming happening, and you want show. In demo what are you doing. like

Comment: I try to create live stream from my iOS app. I'm getting tokens, send request with my app key. All according docs. I tried to send test request from the site. It works fine.

Comment: In fact, can i create live stream for broadcasting?

Comment: Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832722/youtube-api-v3-on-ios-app-my-api-key-does-not-work-but-somebody-elses-key-doe), it might help.

Comment: @noogui thanks a lot. Request really works without bundle id on the API Manager side.

Comment: so you mase it work?

Comment: for now most of requests are working. I built requests in chain and now trying to broadcast live video by lf - live framework.

Comment: I made sample application which using the Live Streaming API https://github.com/SKrotkih/YouTubeLiveVideo

Answer (score 5):

POST Request:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveStreams"];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

 /**
     * set access token in HTTP Header field 
     * get access token after successful  login 
     */
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",_str_access_token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    /**
     * set bundle identifier on Header field
     */
    [request addValue:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier"];
```

Comment: Setting bundle id for HTTP header field worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Where did you get ```X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier``` from? I can't find it in the Google documentation.