# Set Bundle Id for Google APIs Client Library for iOS

Tags: google-api-client, youtube-data-api

Has the issue of setting the bundle identifier for the GoogleAPIClientForREST/YouTube ever been resolved?

I found these but never a resolution or solution:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173446
https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/issues/70

Seems to me if there is a pulldown to set the bundle id, there should be a way to set it in iOS, and there should be something more useful then "remove the bundle id."

Answer (score 1):

I found how to do it by looking at the test source and another post here:

[Test source](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/blob/master/Source/Tests/GTLRServiceTest.m#L341-L342)

[Hint from another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40043972/youtube-live-streaming-api-create-live-stream-is-failed-with-the-request-did/41604675#41604675)

```
    let query = GTLRYouTubeQuery_SearchList.query(withPart: "id,snippet")
    var bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
    bundleIdentifier = bundleIdentifier?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    query.additionalHTTPHeaders = ["X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier" : bundleIdentifier!]
```